# what is the accurate Twitter sentiment analysis solution with Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a CSV file of 20K tweets with all information such as location, username, and date which I want to assign a label positive/neutral/negative to each tweet by Python. 
I used the following Python code from textblob library for **Tweets Sentiment Analysis**.

```
import csv
from textblob import TextBlob
import sys

# Do some version specific stuff
if sys.version[0] == '3':
    from importlib import reload
    sntTweets = csv.writer(open("sentimentTweets.csv", "w", newline=''))

if sys.version[0] == '2':
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
    sntTweets = csv.writer(open("sentimentTweets.csv", "w"))

alltweets = csv.reader(open("Corona.csv", 'r'))

for row in alltweets:
    blob = TextBlob(row[2])
    print (blob.sentiment.polarity)
    if blob.sentiment.polarity > 0:
        sntTweets.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], blob.sentiment.polarity, "positive"])
    elif blob.sentiment.polarity < 0:
        sntTweets.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], blob.sentiment.polarity, "negative"])
    elif blob.sentiment.polarity == 0.0:
        sntTweets.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], blob.sentiment.polarity, "neutral"])
```

this code runs perfect and produces the sentimentTweets.csv file. I like the idea that for each tweet, it gives me two labels: a number between -1 and 1, and also classify tweet to negative/neutral/positive.

but it is not accurate. for example for the following tweet, it assigns positive with the number:0.285714285714285.
*"RT @eliyudin: ‚ÄúI‚Äôll have a Corona... hold the virus!‚Äù -a dad on vacation somewhere in Florida right now"*
but as you can understand, the sentiment of the above tweet should be negative.
How can I make it accurate? and how can I find the accuracy of my output?

Answer (score 1):

TextBlob estimates the polarity based on the polarity of words and chunks of the input (code here: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/e6cd9791ae42e37b5a2132676f9ca69340e8d8c0/textblob/_text.py#L854). Such an approach can get easily confused on noisy texts like Tweets. This is quite hard to improve because it depends on the quality of the underlying language resources.

I would suggest using a fully machine-learned model such as Flair:

```py
import flair
flair_sentiment = flair.models.TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')
s = flair.data.Sentence(sentence)
flair_sentiment.predict(s)
total_sentiment = s.labels
```

It should be also easy to train your model in FastText: https://github.com/charlesmalafosse/FastText-sentiment-analysis-for-tweets

Comment: Thank you for your answer. how can I install FastText?sorry I am pretty new. can you give me more detail?

Comment: If you want to use it inside Python, just do `pip install fasttext`. If you want  a standalone binary or other bindings, follow the instruction on their GitHub: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText

Comment: I use the Python and I tried both ```pip install fasttext``` and ```pip install fastText``` with Mac and Windows computers and for both I got the error: ``` ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
nning setup.py clean for fasttext
Failed to build fasttextInstalling collected packages: fasttext
    Running setup.py install for fasttext ... [?25lerror
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. Perhaps a wrong Python version? Conflict in dependencies? Try googling the error or a separate question here on SO.